# Validate Jwt signature

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, jwt

I have an app with React in the frontend and SpringBoot in the backend for the API,
when I login with some user it saves the token in localStorage and you can modify it.
So, if you modify it and change the values of the token (included the signature) the app doesn't say anything.
The thing is, how can I validate in every request (POST, GET, PUT) that the user's token is valid (signature valid)?

Comment: Try to use [Filter](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-add-filter)

Comment: *if you modify it and change the values of the token (included the signature)the app doesn't say anything* - to sign a token you would need the secret (symmetric algorithm) or the private key (asymmetric algorithm). Both should not be available on the frontend. Therefore you can modify the token, but it will invalidate the signature.

Comment: @jps When i create the jwt it is made with the signature, but the app dont mind if the token is not signed, idk why

Answer (score 0):

To enable validation of a user's JWT token you'll have to configure Spring Security with OAuth2 in your project, specifically the Resource Server.

To do this you'll have to add this dependency to your project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Then add something like this to your application.yml:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          jwk-set-uri: http://localhost:8083/auth/realms/.../protocol/openid-connect/certs
```

> JWTs include all the information within the Token, so the Resource Server needs to verify the Token’s signature to make sure the data has not been modified. The jwk-set-uri property contains the public key that the server can use for this purpose.

And then configure HTTP security itself, e.g.:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
              .authorizeRequests()
                ...
                .anyRequest()
                  .authenticated()
            .and()
              .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt();
    }
}
```

References:

- https://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-spring-oauth2-angular
- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-jwt
- https://auth0.com/blog/spring-boot-authorization-tutorial-secure-an-api-java/